# I have an iframe that expands and when opened, i want it to resize based on the content. Here is my iframe logic. Any suggestions please?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cognos-10

I have an iframe that expands and when opened, i want it to resize based on the content.  Here is my iframe logic.  Any suggestions please?  Here is my iframe script:

```
<div id="filterblock2" style="display:none;width:305px;">
<iframe id="Filters" frameBorder="0" width="370px"  height="1430px" style="display:block;"scrolling="no" src=""></iframe>
<script>
document.getElementById("Filters").src ="../cognosURLrun.outputFormat=&run.prompt=false&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false";
</script>
```